# ngx-bootstrap datepicker not align to right of text box

Tags: angular, css, ngx-bootstrap

Using ngx-bootstrap datepicker with angular4. I want the date picker to align bottom right of text box. But when I use placement="bottom right" the datepicker starts from end of text box. Where as my requirement is the datepicker should end   below the textbox should not go beyond the textbox are. I want the datepicker to be aligned exactly below the textbox.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
  <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
        #dp="bsDatepicker"
         placement="bottom right"
        bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="myDateValue">
</div>
```

[image]

Need something like below:
[image]

Comment: Did you find how to do it?